# using dplyr to arrange/delete data in R

Tags: r, dplyr

```
._883<-quantmod::getSymbols("0883.HK",from="2022-04-21",to="2022-12-22",auto.assign = FALSE)
._600938<-quantmod::getSymbols("600938.SS",from="2022-04-21",to="2022-12-22",auto.assign = FALSE)

._883<-._883[,6]
._600938<-._600938[,6]
spread<-data.frame(._883,._600938)

> length(._883)
[1] 169
> length(._600938)
[1] 165
```

Both arrays are indexed by date; If I want to use `dplyr` library here and I would like to find out the missing data in `._600938` then delete the entire row, including `._883` (that way I can align the data using the same date), may I ask how can I do so using `dplyr`. Thanks so much for helping.

Hi guys, instead of using `dplyr` library, I try the below method:

```
x<-cbind(._883,._600938)
na.omit(x)
x$spread<-x[,2]-x[,1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the dplyr library to find the missing data in ._600938 and delete the entire row including ._883, you can use the filter() function to select only the rows that have missing values in the ._600938 column, and then use the select(-1) function to exclude the ._883 column and keep only the ._600938 column. You can then use the anti_join() function to remove the rows with missing data from spread:

```
library(dplyr)

# Select rows with missing values in the ._600938 column and exclude the ._883 column
missing_data <- spread %>% filter(is.na(._600938)) %>% select(-1)

# Remove rows with missing data from spread
spread_clean <- spread %>% anti_join(missing_data)
```

Alternatively, you can use the complete() function from the tidyr library to fill in the missing values with a default value, such as 0 or NA:

```
library(tidyr)

# Fill in missing values with NA
spread_complete <- spread %>% complete(._883, ._600938)

# Fill in missing values with 0
spread_complete <- spread %>% complete(._883, ._600938, fill = list(._600938 = 0))
```

Note that the complete() function will add rows to the data frame if there are any dates in either ._883 or ._600938 that are not present in both. If you do not want to add rows to the data frame, you can use the full_join() function from the dplyr library instead:

```
library(dplyr)

# Join spread with missing data filled in with NA
spread_complete <- spread %>% full_join(missing_data, by = c("._883", "._600938"))

# Join spread with missing data filled in with 0
spread_complete <- spread %>% full_join(missing_data, by = c("._883", "._600938")) %>%
  mutate(._600938 = ifelse(is.na(._600938), 0, _.600938))
```

I hope it helps!